# ZXing .net MAUI: How to create border around barcode scanner view?

Tags: .net, zxing, maui

I am new to .net MAUI and want to create barcode scanner view using ZXing library

I want to put some custom border around scanning view (camera capture screen). How can I create these border something like in this picture? Which layout, controls do I need for this?

Here is the picture that I'd like to create

[image]

Comment: You might want to read about Skia sharp! to learn how to draw lines manually:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/draw?view=net-maui-7.0

or you can draw the "white box image" around your zxing barcode view! Look into the "Draw an image" section on the link I shared above.

There's many example how to draw strokes